# transfer and save data from Arduino to Matlab

Tags: matlab, arduino

I have an arduino and an e-Health Sensor Platform V2.0 that receive some data. I want to transfer and save those data to Matlab for processing them. Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: So what is the **specific** problem that you're having? We aren't going to read the docs for you, you know.....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidelines on how to write questions. For starters: 1. Please add more code to your question to show us what you have tried, and for future readers to benefit from this question. 2. Look for other questions or documentation which might help you out already. For example http://in.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/arduinoio/read-and-write-data.html  3. Whenever you ask a question, please be specific and better yet, give us a minimum working example. SO users are here to help you, but not to write your entire code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup Serial Communication between Arduino and MATLAB. There are lot's of example code in internet for that. Arduino's Serial communication is normal but for MATLAB , you need to setup the serial communication for that to synchronize baud rate,data size etc with arduino. A sample code to setup serial is given below , but you have to change it according to your need.

```
function[obj,flag] = setupSerial(comPort)
% It accept as the entry value, the index of the serial port
% Arduino is connected to, and as output values it returns the serial 
% element obj and a flag value used to check if when the script is compiled
% the serial element exists yet.
flag = 1;
% Initialize Serial object
obj = serial(comPort);
set(obj,'DataBits',8);
set(obj,'StopBits',1);
set(obj,'BaudRate',9600);
set(obj,'Parity','none');
fopen(obj);
a = 'b';
while (a~='a') 
   a=fread(obj,1,'uchar');
end
if (a=='a')
    disp('Serial read');
end
fprintf(obj,'%c','a');
mbox = msgbox('Serial Communication setup'); uiwait(mbox);
fscanf(obj,'%u');
end
```

For more info , ask google . :p